# ManagedBean keeps returning same query results (Session/View Scope?)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following in an index.xhtml page.

```
<h:form id="findForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">                
            <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="name"/>
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{finder.name}"/>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Find"
                action="#{finder.gotoFoundPage}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And here's a cut down version of the next page, found.xhtml.

```
    <p:dataTable id="myTable" var="item" 
        value="#{finder.byName}" rowKey="#{item.name}" 
        paginator="true" rows="20" 
        selection="#{finder.selectedItem}" selectionMode="single">

        <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{item.name}"
                filterBy="#{item.name}" id="name">
            #{item.name}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Both xhtml pages use the same mananged bean. When I click on the CommandButton from index.xhtml, it navigates to the found.xhtml page which also uses the Finder bean (currently ViewScoped). The problem is that the Finder bean will not get the #{finder.name} (which user inputs in index page and needs to be passed to found page) unless I make the Finder bean SessionScoped.

So if I make it SessionScoped, then the problem is that found.xhtml page keeps displaying the same values in the found page upon a new search at the man page. The same values even though the values in the database have changed. My understanding is that if I make it ViewScoped, it will perform a new query each time the page loads in order to update the displayed values. But not sure how to do this.

```
@EJBs({@EJB(name="ejb/MyBean1", beanInterface=IMyBean1.class),
       @EJB(name="ejb/MyBean2", beanInterface=IMyBean2.class)})
@ManagedBean(name="finder")
@ViewScoped
public class Finder implements Serializable {

    // ...

    public String gotoFoundPage() {
        return "found?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that whenever you use the `?faces-redirect=true` trick, the user's browser will redirect with an HTTP GET request and that causes JSF to clean any state stored in the view.
So, even if you use an `@ViewScoped` bean, after a redirect you will get a brand new instance.

In your case, as it is a simple search, you may want to do it using view params, if the data isn't sensitive to appear in the URL. Check out [this blog post from BalusC: Communication in JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) for more information about this and other stuff related to passing data around JSF beans and pages.

Comment: Something sounds like we're not on the same page, but almost. It currently is ViewScoped, and after a redirect I am not getting a brand new instance, so no clean state. Rather, each time I input text for a search from the index page, it redirects me to the found page and yet the data is still old after I've already updated the database fields with new data. I'll take a look at view params in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: You could also postback to the same view and render the results conditionally.

Comment: @Ender well, you get the old data when you use session scope, but that's expeceted. So, session scope is probably not what you want. Another good option as the comment above says, is putting both the search form and the results in the same page and render them conditionally. If you don't need to put the search form in every page, that may be a good try.